# How to set author of SVN commit using SharpSVN library in c#

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

I use SharpSvn library from CollabNET. I would like to set revision author while commiting, but I always end up with a commit with my Windows user name.

This does not work for me:

```
System.Net.NetworkCredential oCred = new
    System.Net.NetworkCredential("user"​, "pass");
client.Authentication.DefaultCredentials = oCred;
```

I've tried also:

```
client.SetProperty("", "svn:author", "user");
```

But I get an error that target (first argument) is bad.

So could you please tell me how to set user (author) of commit to subversion repository in c#?

Comment: You should use .SetRevisionProperty() for changing revision properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This all depends on how you connect to your repository, as the repository is responsible for adding a username to the revision. (It usually copies the credentials for the connections but it doesn't have to do that).

When you use a file:/// repository (which is usually not recommended - See [The Subversion Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)) you can work around this directly on the commit.

```
using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
    client.Authentication.Clear(); // Clear predefined handlers

    // Install a custom username handler
    client.Authentication.UserNameHandlers +=
        delegate(object sender, SvnUserNameEventArgs e)
        {
            e.UserName = "MyName";
        };

    SvnCommitArgs ca = new SvnCommitArgs { LogMessage = "Hello" }
    client.Commit(dir, ca);
}
```

If you connect to a remote repository you can change the author of a revision when a pre-revprop-change hook is installed in the repository (See [The Subversion Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/))

```
using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
    client.SetRevisionProperty(new Uri("http://my/repository"), 12345,
                              SvnPropertyNames.SvnAuthor,
                              "MyName");

    // Older SharpSvn releases allowed only the now obsolete syntax
    client.SetRevisionProperty(
        new SvnUriTarget(new Uri("http://my/repository"), 12345),
        SvnPropertyNames.SvnAuthor,
        "MyName");

}
```

[2009-08-14]
More recent SharpSvn releases also allow this:

```
using (SvnRepositoryClient rc = new SvnRepositoryClient())
{
   SvnSetRevisionPropertyRepositoryArgs ra;
   ra.CallPreRevPropChangeHook = false;
   ra.CallPostRevPropChangeHook = false;
   rc.SetRevisionProperty(@"C:\Path\To\Repository", 12345,
                         SvnPropertyNames.SvnAuthor, "MyName", ra);
}
```

This last example assumes direct file access to the repository, but it bypasses repository hooks for optimal performance.